# Vim and Python says the encoding is ANSI_X3.4-1968

Tags: vim, python, unicode

In Vim, the following command (using Python 3.4.3) outputs `ANSI_X3.4-1968`:

`:!python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)"`

However, I want UTF-8 **everywhere**.

In `.vimrc`, I do have `set encoding=utf-8` and my locale is set correctly to `nb_NO.UTF-8`.

UTF-8 in general works fine. The only problem is when executing commands with `:!` in Vim.

How can I run the command above, in Vim, in a way that makes the output become `UTF-8`?

Comment: `!PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)"
` does the job for me but I'm sure there's a better way

Comment: Thank you! Setting `PYTHONIOENCODING` to `utf-8` works. How incredibly peculiar that this isn't the default everywhere, though.

Comment: @Alexander See http://bugs.python.org/issue13643 for why it is not the default.

Comment: @iruvar, if you want to write your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

In python or other scripting language, you have shebang line in first line such as :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then you can specify your encoding in line 2 such as :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Of course second line only work on python.